# What is a correct way to import "RPi.GPIO as GPIO" for use in a python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I have a python program to which I am adding GPIO pin control functionality. It is a multi-threaded system that runs fine until I try to do an "import RPi.GPIO as GPIO". Then I get the error below:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/System/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    from LightUpAlarm import AlarmCli
  File "/usr/local/System/LightUpAlarm/AlarmCli.py", line 26, in <module>
    from AlarmManager import AlarmManager
ImportError: No module named AlarmManager`

The module "AlarmManager" was available until I tried to import "RPi.GPIO". I would appreciate any help understanding what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Pastebin link to full python file generating error. [AlarmThread.py](http://pastebin.com/QiDs86zH)

Comment: The error is not directly related to the import line you gave. Please post all code required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KlausD. I have just added a pastebin link to the complete thread file. I commented out the GPIO import in the imports section and it finds all modules and system runs fine. What is puzzling me is why importing GPIO  in this specific file generates the issue of not finding modules.